# Changing nestedStackCount in serverless-plugin-split-stacks

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

Since CloudFormation has a limit of 500 resources, we are splitting our stack with the [serverless-plugin-split-stacks](https://github.com/dougmoscrop/serverless-plugin-split-stacks) plugin. Recently, we have run out of the resources this way as well. The documentation specifies that

> Once set, the `nestedStackCount` configuration should never be changed because the only reliable method of changing it later on is to recreate the deployment from scratch.

My configuration is the following currently:

```
splitStacks:
  nestedStackCount: 20
  perFunction: false
  perType: false
  perGroupFunction: true
```

What's a safe way to change my configuration and increase the `nestedStackCount` without breaking anything? My current deployment has the following steps:

```
- npm install -g serverless
- sls prune -n 10
- sls deploy
```

The error I'm receiving is the following:

```
$ sls deploy
Running "serverless" from node_modules
Compiling with Typescript...
Using local tsconfig.json - tsconfig.json
Typescript compiled.
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: Summary: 248 resources migrated into 20 nested stacks
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: ├─ (root): 515
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  ├─ Outputs: 3
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  └─ Parameters: 0 (References: 1323)
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: ├─ 10NestedStack: 18
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  ├─ Outputs: 5
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  └─ Parameters: 9 (References: 5)
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: ├─ 11NestedStack: 26
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  ├─ Outputs: 3
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  └─ Parameters: 9 (References: 22)
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: ├─ 12NestedStack: 15
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  ├─ Outputs: 5
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  └─ Parameters: 7 (References: 5)
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: ├─ 13NestedStack: 9
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  ├─ Outputs: 3
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  └─ Parameters: 8 (References: 3)
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: ├─ 14NestedStack: 6
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  ├─ Outputs: 2
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  └─ Parameters: 7 (References: 2)
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: ├─ 15NestedStack: 10
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  ├─ Outputs: 2
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  └─ Parameters: 7 (References: 5)
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: ├─ 16NestedStack: 6
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  ├─ Outputs: 2
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  └─ Parameters: 7 (References: 2)
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: ├─ 17NestedStack: 9
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  ├─ Outputs: 3
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  └─ Parameters: 7 (References: 3)
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: ├─ 18NestedStack: 18
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  ├─ Outputs: 6
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  └─ Parameters: 7 (References: 6)
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: ├─ 19NestedStack: 3
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  ├─ Outputs: 1
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  └─ Parameters: 7 (References: 1)
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: ├─ 1NestedStack: 18
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  ├─ Outputs: 6
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  └─ Parameters: 8 (References: 6)
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: ├─ 20NestedStack: 12
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  ├─ Outputs: 3
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  └─ Parameters: 9 (References: 4)
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: ├─ 2NestedStack: 8
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  ├─ Outputs: 2
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  └─ Parameters: 7 (References: 2)
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: ├─ 3NestedStack: 14
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  ├─ Outputs: 2
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  └─ Parameters: 7 (References: 11)
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: ├─ 4NestedStack: 4
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  ├─ Outputs: 0
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  └─ Parameters: 6 (References: 3)
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: ├─ 5NestedStack: 21
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  ├─ Outputs: 7
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  └─ Parameters: 7 (References: 7)
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: ├─ 6NestedStack: 18
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  ├─ Outputs: 6
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  └─ Parameters: 8 (References: 6)
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: ├─ 7NestedStack: 15
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  ├─ Outputs: 4
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  └─ Parameters: 9 (References: 5)
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: ├─ 8NestedStack: 15
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  ├─ Outputs: 5
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: │  └─ Parameters: 8 (References: 5)
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]: └─ 9NestedStack: 3
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]:    ├─ Outputs: 0
[serverless-plugin-split-stacks]:    └─ Parameters: 7 (References: 1)
× Stack failed to deploy (134s)
Environment: linux, node 18.17.1, framework 3.26.0 (local) 3.36.0v (global), plugin 6.2.2, SDK 4.3.2
Credentials: Local, environment variables
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
Error:
The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template format error: Number of resources, 515, is greater than maximum allowed, 500
```

Would this break the deployment if I increased the `nestedStackCount`? What's the best way to do that without braking anything?

Thanks in advance!